# Not Working: Redaction of Spark Environment Variable

Tags: python, apache-spark, emr, redaction

I am using the following to add a spark job step to a running emr v5.11.1 cluster on AWS, using python 3.6.5 boto3 and spark 2.2.1:

```
myemr = boto3.client('emr',region_name=os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'])            
response = myemr.add_job_flow_steps(
            JobFlowId=my_emr_id,
            Steps=[
                {
                    'Name': key,
                    'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
                    'HadoopJarStep': {
                        'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                        'Args': [
                            'spark-submit',
                            '--deploy-mode', 'cluster',
                            '--master', 'yarn',
                            '--conf',  'spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.my_password=sensitive_value',
                            '--conf',  'spark.redaction.regex=password',
                            '--class', 'com.myApp', 's3a://myjarurl.jar',
                            '-c', 's3a://s3bucket_myconfig_location',
                            '-w', 'myconfig.json',
                            '-e', 'prod',
                            '-n', 'demo'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        )
```

The step is running ok and able to access the yarn environment variable.  But the sensitive_value is not redacted from logs or AWS EMR Console, steps tab.  I see `--conf`,  `spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.my_password=sensitive_value` displayed in both.

I would like for either the variable spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.my_password to be completely removed from logs and console, or the sensitive_value to be replaced with something like ***.

Reading the apache spark doc https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/configuration.html I thought this would work.  Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: For me it worked with `"(?i)secret|password|dsn"`, as I need to mask entries with secred, password and dsn in them. The `(?i)` is just to enable case-insensitiveness.

Comment: @martinarroyo - can you give complete example of this. I am stuck at this and not able to go ahead.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I meant something like `spark.redaction.regex=(?i)secret|password|dsn`.